# How do I add a parameter dynamically to jekyll-timeago plugin?

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions

This seems like a really trivial problem, but I can't seem to make it work.
I'm trying to add [jekyll-timeago](https://github.com/markets/jekyll-timeago) plugin to jekyll. In the example docs, it says that if I wanted to add a parameter, I can do this:

`{{ page.date | timeago: '2020-1-1' }}`

But what if my parameter is a variable? Here is my code:

```
{% if exp.durationEnd == 'Present'  %} 
   {% assign endDate = site.time %}                        
{% else %}
   {% assign endDate = exp.durationEnd %}
{% endif %}

<div>{{ exp.durationStart }} – {{ exp.durationEnd }} ( {{ exp.durationStart | timeago: '{{ endDate }}' }} ) </div>
```

I can't seem to make it work. Extra emphasis on:

`{{ exp.durationStart | timeago: '{{ endDate }}' }}`

The code results in:

`2 years and 8 months' }}` with that extra `' }}` which I think is wrong.

I have tried various expressions like the following but to no avail:

`{{ exp.durationStart | timeago: endDate }}`

`{{ exp.durationStart | timeago: '{% endDate %}' }}`

`{% assign endDate = timeago exp.durationStart site.time %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nvm.. I got it.

```
{{ exp.durationStart }} – {{ exp.durationEnd }} ( {{ exp.durationStart | timeago : endDate }} )
```